# Can MTP devices be efficiently handled by Files?

Tags: pantheon-files, mtp, android

I have poor experience when connecting an MTP device on elementary. More specifically, I'm referring to connecting my Android phone in order to transfer files from/to the file manager. Here are the issues I encounter:

- The volume corresponding to my phone's storage correctly appears in the sidepane of Files. Clicking on it correctly mounts it but a message appears in the main window saying I do not own that folder and so I can't access the files in it at all.
- Without unmounting it, I can access the volume only by opening Files with admin privileges, which of course shouldn't be a default method. But the condition is that the volume is already mounted in the normal-user instance of Files, otherwise I can't mount it directly from the admin window.
- It is possibile to move, transfer, delete files etc. but actually, in the case of copying for example, it always results in what appears to be partial transfers and thus corrupted files, i.e. a 200MB file *looks* correctly transferred from PC to phone when actually 180MB of it have been actually copied.

What experience do you have? Is this a Ubuntu-related issue or something Files cannot handle properly?

Comment: Hey @saintjules, I've voted to close your question as being "too broad" for the stack exchange format. Typically questions should have only 1 answer and answers should not be opinion based or anecdotal. Additionally, it looks like what you might want to do instead of ask a question here is make a series of reports so that a developer can confirm and fix your issues. The best way to do this is to visit [this website](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files) and follow the elementary [bug reporting guide](https://elementary.io/docs/code/reference#reporting-bugs)

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid it would be too broad, no problem. But hey, it's a beta, I wanted to experiment with questions :)